# Add One Month to a Date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have an input field that needs to be incremented by one month using the JavaScript Date object.  Below is an example of an effort I have made in incrementing the month.  The issue with this seems to be that it will display 0 as January and does not increment the year.

```
nDate.setDate(nDate.getDate());
inputBox1.value = (nDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (nDate.getDate()) + "/" +  (nDate.getFullYear());
```

Comment: Question: what happens if that date is 01/31/2010? Do wish to see 01/28/2010 or 03/03/2010?

Comment: Voting to re-open since it apparently is a real question - 30k views, reasonable answer with 24 upvotes....

Comment: @ben I think your comment assumes that the month has 30 days?

Comment: @supersan - true, that was shortsighted of me! Deleted.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use [`Date.setMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth):

```js
var d = new Date(2000, 0, 1); // January 1, 2000
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
console.log(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate());
```

`Date.setMonth` is range proof i.e. months other than 0...11 are adjusted automatically.

Answer (score -6):

You'll have to get the text out of the text box, which you can then pass to the Date() constructor:

`var d = new Date(text);`

Then format the date string:

`var str = d.getDate(), d.getMonth() + 1, d.getFullYear()`

And set the test box to that value

Comment: what about december --> january

Comment: Hmm, I thought it rolled, but maybe you'll have to explicitly check for that. Or there could be a better way entirely

Comment: i dont understand your line how its creating a date, it seems like it will create something like 30, 4, 1002

Comment: My bad, copy+pasted from one of my apps that does it slightly differently!

Comment: @leora adding one month to December will cause a year roll.  What I don't know is what happens if you roll from the end of a long month into a shorter month.