# Increase one month using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two date input field. I need to increase one month and set that value to second input field. This what I tried, used DD/MM/YYYY date format.

```
var f= new Date($(#firstDate).val());
f.setMonth( f.getMonth( ) + 1 );
seconddate = ( f.getMonth( ) + 1 ) + '/' + f.getDate( ) + '/' + f.getFullYear( );
$(#secondDate).val(seconddate);
```

This is the results i'm getting in console.

```
var f= new Date(19/06/2016);
f.setMonth( f.getMonth( ) + 1 );
seconddate = ( f.getMonth( ) + 1 ) + '/' + f.getDate( ) + '/' + f.getFullYear( );
"2/1/1970"
```

Comment: Use http://momentjs.com/ -- it is the standard solution tom most anything date related.

Comment: Please post HTML. Also, where is variable `f` defined?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848673/add-one-month-to-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: Add quotes here: `new Date(19/06/2016);` => `new Date("19/06/2016");` because 19/06/2016 is 0.0015707671957671957 (math divide).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change variable `f` in the code to `first`

**Original Code**

```
var first = new Date($(#firstDate).val());
f.setMonth( f.getMonth( ) + 1 );
seconddate = ( f.getMonth( ) + 1 ) + '/' + f.getDate( ) + '/' + f.getFullYear( );
$(#secondDate).val(seconddate);
```

**Corrected Code**

```
var first = new Date($(#firstDate).val());
first.setMonth( first.getMonth( ) + 1 );
var seconddate = ( first.getMonth( ) + 1 ) + '/' + first.getDate( ) + '/' + first.getFullYear( );
$(#secondDate).val(seconddate);
```

**Example**

```
var firstDate = "19/06/2016";
var firstDateSplit = firstDate.split("/");
var first = new Date(firstDateSplit[2], firstDateSplit[1] - 1, firstDateSplit[0]);
first.setMonth( first.getMonth( ) + 1 );
var seconddate = ( first.getMonth( ) + 1 ) + '/' + first.getDate( ) + '/' + first.getFullYear( );
```

Comment: try var f= new Date("06/19/2016");

Comment: Check the example @Shahmee

Comment: Did you check the example.This will works in your case @Shahmee

Answer (score 0):

```js
var future = new Date(); // get today date
future.setDate(future.getDate() + 30);
var finalDate = future.getFullYear() +'-'+ ((future.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (future.getMonth() + 1) +'-'+ future.getDate();
console.log(finalDate);
```

```
var future = new Date(); // get today date
future.setDate(future.getDate() + 30);
var finalDate = future.getFullYear() +'-'+ ((future.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (future.getMonth() + 1) +'-'+ future.getDate();

// Below closure-date is input 
setTimeout(function(){ $("#closure-date").val(finalDate); }, 100);
```

Answer (score -1):

Constructor `new Date()` accepts only date format `MM/DD/YYYY`, not the `DD/MM/YYYY`.

When you input "19/06/2016" it gets parsed as 19 months and 6 days after year 2016 which results in date 2017-06-06.

Then you add two months (one in `f.setMonth( f.getMonth( ) + 1 );` and second in `seconddate = ( f.getMonth( ) + 1 ) ...` which results to 8/6/2017.

Your console example returns year 1970, because unquoted 19/06/2016 is mathematical operation with result 0.0015707671957671957.

As suggested by others, use momentsJS or parse the date yourself.

Answer (score -2):

I would always use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) for date operations - just to be save, there are too many special cases in date operations.

Here is a solution with moment.js:

```
var f = moment($('#firstDate').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY");
if(f.isValid()) {
    $('#secondDate').val(f.add(1, 'months').toDate());
}
```

Comment: Using moment alone won't prevent *"garbage in - garbage out"* which is problem OP has. Will still require providing format

Comment: @charlietfl well, you can obviously add the format to the moment constructor, but it is save in regards of adding a month and getting a valid date.

Comment: So are OP's methods if  valid date is constructed. You are not solving OP's problem which is the whole purpose of an answer

Comment: Why is my answer not solving the problem of the OP? It parses the date, adds one month and puts it to another input field. Exactly what he wanted. And how is that in every case valid: `f.setMonth( f.getMonth( ) + 1 );` Have you heard of December (+1 month)?

Comment: Well it didn't until you just edited it. Also javascript Date object knows to move to next month and year when you add one month to december and will return january...that's not an issue